# Converting NOAA netcdf file to geo tif

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

SI'm trying to convert [this netcdf file](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/climo/newhail.nc) to geo tif using python or gdal, but with no succes.
Here is my approach in python:

```
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio('path/to/nc')
rds.newhail.rio.to_raster('path/to/tif')
```

Then I try to visualize it in QGIS but can't see anything.

Next I tried to set crs (stored in global attributes of nc file - map_proj = "+proj=lcc +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs") with gdalwarp:

```
gdalwarp -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM -t_srs '+proj=lcc +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs' newhail.tif newhail_crs.tif
```

Now I can see the tif in QGIS but the coordinates are compeltly wrong. See attached picture - data should be for US, not in Africa.
[image] What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You normally only use `gdalwarp` if you want to change something (like projection), for converting or assigning metadata `gdal_translate` is probably better since it doesn't change the actual data itself.

Ideally you have a bit more information about the source, because this file is a little messy. It stores the coordinates as lat/lon, but the grid (the data) is in this LCC projection.

One thing you can do is convert the lat/lon back to that projection. Assuming those coordinates are the center of the pixels, expand by half the resolution (40km) to get the outer extent, and assign that using `gdal_translate` in the conversion to tiff.

Something like that would give:

`gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs" -a_ullr -2853244.2412856636 3284372.1657427647 2746755.7587143364 -315627.83425723313 NETCDF:"newhail.nc":newhail newhail.tif`

That puts it in the right ballpark, but it remains messy, and the data is too low resolution to eyeball it. The boundingbox doesn't seem to approximate something nicely rounded, which is often the case (but doesn't have to be of course).

[image]